# Ruby detect socket close while recv

Tags: ruby, sockets

I have a ruby socket client connecting to a server that will close the connection anytime.
Here is my code:

```
@conn = TCPSocket.new address[0], address[1]
while xml = @conn.recv(4096)
  // do something
end
```

How can I detect socket close here?

Answer (score 1):

You may have answered this for yourself already, but for the record...

The recv method blocks until either at least one byte is available, or the socket is closed.  You can therefore loop until recv returns the empty string:

```
@conn = TCPSocket.new address[0], address[1]
while true
  xml = @conn.recv(4096)
  break if xml.empty?
  // do something
end
```